# PHP: Accessing variables created with add_action()

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, elementor

I'm kinda learning php as I go along here (though I do have some experience in other languages), so I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using an add_action() function in functions.php to access the form data from an Elementor form. Works fine from within add_action(), however I cannot return any of the variables to make them available elsewhere within functions.php (I've tried adding "return $fields").

There's probably an easy solution, but I've been wracking my brain all weekend, and haven't gotten anywhere. Any thoughts?

Side Note: I've read elsewhere that using filters may be a solution, but it doesn't seem to be as simple as changing "add_action()" to "add_filter()".

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', function( $record ) {
    $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    if ( 'MyElementorForm' !== $form_name ) {
        return;
    }

    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
    $fields = [];
    foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
        $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
    }
    $letter_type = $fields['LetterType'];

    // Send Test Email //
    if($letter_type === "1"){
        $message = "Upload";
    } elseif($letter_type === "0"){
        $message = "PDF";
    } else {
        $message = "Fail " . gettype($letter_type) . " " . $letter_type;
    }

    mail(
        "my@email_address.com",
        "Test",
        "Test Message " . $message
    );}, 10, 2);
```

Comment: You can pass a variable as parameter to an anonymous function (https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). For alternatives, you can always store it as a global variable or call another function and pass the data to that function. See also: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: If you want to run code when a new record is created, this is the hook you should be using.  All the hooks are listed here.  You can execute any code you want or save data to a database or file if you want to work with it later, etc.  What are you trying to accomplish when a new record is created?
https://developers.elementor.com/forms-api/#Form_New_Record_Action